How can I optimize the loading performance of my website by consolidating multiple <style> elements generated from compiled SCSS into fewer elements?
I am using vue v2 to make and setup a site.
I have made multipe scss-files in the 'component'-directory.
i'm talking about a relatively big site, so there is about 60 scss files.
when my site loads, i get this in the dom tree:
<style type="text/css">(css-code here)</style>
<style type="text/css">(css-code here)</style>
<style type="text/css">(css-code here)</style>

...x60
as you can see my scss compiles into css, but gives way to many style-attributes/stylesheets. this means my site has to go through alot of unnecessary HTTP requests to get all of the css. i'm trying to make it so that after my scss compiles into css BUT BEFORE my site loads, it all gets put in fewer style-elements. i've tried this so far:
i've tried working with gulp to minimize the css and possibly give less stylesheets in my DOM when it loads.
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');

function combineCSS() {
    return gulp.src(['src/components/**/*.scss', '!src/components/combined/**/*.scss']) 
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('styles.css')) // compiled css, but with errors
        .pipe(cleanCSS()) 
        .pipe(inlineCss()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest')); 
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch('src/components/**/*.scss', combineCSS); 
}

exports.combineCSS = combineCSS;
exports.watch = watch;

yet, gulp wants to write away the css into another file before using it, that's not really what I want here. So, when the site loads it already has the knowledge to convert to css, can I not just adjust that function to give me less style-attributes?
I've also tried postcss, but to no avail:
/** @type {import('postcss-load-config').Config} */
const config = {
    plugins: [
      require('autoprefixer'),
      require('postcss-nested'),
      require('postcss-merge-rules')
    ]
  }
  
  module.exports = config

lastly, calling the gulpfile in my script (package.json) doesnt minimize the css or doesnt compile it into one 'style'-dom element. (script serve starts my frontend)
"scripts": {
    "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build  && gulp combineCSS",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "gulp": "npx gulp"
  }

thanks for your time, If I forgot to give specific information, feel free to comment

If you‘re site is using HTTP/2 in production it’s not too much of a concern. (Doesn’t solve your problem of course).

thanks for answering! Unfortunately, we are using HTTP1.1 and would like to drastically reduce the http requests coming from all the scss files (via programming, not manually). Is there not a way to put all of the styles together after SCSS becomes CSS, so during build?

Sure, just haven't touched gulp in years, so not really the person to answer.
